# Most efficient way to constrain parameter type based on another parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a list of car brands, I have a car factory that takes a car and an options object that differ depending on the brand.

```
type CarBrand = 'mazda' | 'toyota' | 'hyundai';

export function CarFactory(car: 'mazda', options: { a: string; b: string }): object;
export function CarFactory(car: 'toyota', options: { b: string; c: string; d: string }): object;
export function CarFactory(car: 'hyundai', options: { e: string; f: string; g: number }): object;
export function CarFactory(car: CarBrand, options: any): object {
  return options;
}
```

This works for me at the moment, but if I have more car brands in the future it would be rather laborious adding new type signatures to overload the function. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be inclined to make an interface representing the mapping from brand name to options, and then make your `CarFactory` function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).  Like this:

```
interface CarBrandOptions {
    mazda: { a: string; b: string };
    toyota: { b: string; c: string; d: string };
    hyundai: { e: string; f: string; g: number };
}

type CarBrand = keyof CarBrandOptions;

function CarFactory<K extends CarBrand>(car: K, options: CarBrandOptions[K]): object {
    return options;
}
```

This will act the same way that your current code does, I think:

```
CarFactory("mazda", { a: "", b: "" }); // okay

CarFactory("toyota", { a: "", b: "" }); // error! 
// Argument of type '{ a: string; b: string; }' 
// is not assignable to parameter of type '{ b: string; c: string; d: string; }'.

CarFactory("toyota", { b: "", c: "", d: "" }); //okay
```

but will make it easier to add more car brands by adding properties to or merging properties into the `CarBrandOptions` interface.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Comment: Thanks @jcalz! Would you also happen to know why if I omit <K extends CarBrand> the constraints don't work correctly?

Comment: What do you mean "omit"?  If you make the signature non-generic then the best you can do is accept all possible `CarBrand` for the first argument and all possible `CarBrandOptions[CarBrand]` for the second argument.  But that will accept mismatched parameters.  The generic specifically says that whatever `K` is used for the first argument, the second argument needs to be `CarBrandOptions[K]`.  The generic parameter allows you to express the correlation between the first and second arguments in a way that a non-generic signature can't.